# Cx_freeze - How can I Install the shared libraries to /usr/lib

Tags: python, shared-libraries, compiled

I am using cx_freeze to compile my python script and when I compile the program, all the files are placed in one specified folder. The executable wont run if the shared libs are not within the same directory.

How would I set it up so the executable looks within /usr/lib/PROGRAMNAME/ to run the libraries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bbfreeze` will put everything in a single executable.

Comment: I will keep this as the current solution although, I do want to be able to use libraries instead of making a single executable.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with the following cx_Freeze command :

```
python3 setup.py install --prefix=/usr
```

This will deploy:

1. all generated files (`*.so`, `library.zip` and included files) into `/usr/lib/YourAppName/`
2. `/usr/bin/yourapp` symlinking to `/usr/lib/YourAppName/yourapp`.